# Need Help in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page as shown in this picture, but it is not displaying the same.

[image]

```css
#addcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
#addprimary {
  float: left;
  max-width: 125px;
}
#addsecondary {
  float: right;
  width: 125px;
}
#addcontent {
  margin: auto;
  width: 740px;
  height: 390px;
  background: url(../img/home_page/home.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="addcontainer">
  <div id="addprimary">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/183798-18HhJR1392119968.jpg">>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="addcontent">
  </div>

  <div id="addsecondary">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/183798-18HhJR1392119968.jpg">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this -

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}

#addcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
#addprimary {
  float: left;
  max-width: 125px;
  
}
#addsecondary {
  float: right;
  width: 125px;
}
#addcontent {
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  /*width: 740px;*/
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 390px;
  background: url(http://img.reflex.cz/img/3/full/2394140-img-windows.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size:  740px 390px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="addcontainer">
  <div id="addprimary">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/183798-18HhJR1392119968.jpg">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="addcontent">
  </div>

  <div id="addsecondary">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/183798-18HhJR1392119968.jpg">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should use boostrap , if you need custom class then you can just re-work any bootstrap class you want.

In bootstrap it will look like this :

```html
<div class="col-md-12">  
  <div class="col-md-2">
  left side
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  middle
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  right side
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css :

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}

#addcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
#addprimary,#addsecondary  {
width:18%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;

}

#addcontent {
    margin:0 20px;
 display:inline-block;

  width: 55%;
  height: 390px;
  background: url(http://www.personal.psu.edu/afr3/blogs/siowfa13/Tigers-animals-20238015-2493-1983.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:  100% 100%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/souraj/t2rx7n0c/

you can use display:inline-block to display the elements.